# Thunderbird (v115.3.2 64-bit) Outbox Count of Emails Waiting to be Sent

Tags: email, count, directory, thunderbird

Does anyone know if there is a way in Thunderbird Email to have the Outbox give you a count of the emails waiting to be sent?

Emails waiting to be sent used to go in the Outbox as Unread so you would get the normal Unread count on the folder.  Since the latest update they go in as read so there's no count on the folder any more.

Version used - Thunderbird Version 115.3.2 (64-bit) for Windows.

Thank you!

UPDATE Feb 2024 - The Thunderbird Dev team have fixed this and the latest version is showing the Outbox count again.  Many Thanks!!!

Comment: Is there a setting in the Config Editor perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

This bug [was reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1852428) as "Messages in outbox not shown as unread (by default) in Thunderbird 115.2.0"

Looks like it [was just fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1852428) by John Bielin and Magnus Melin!  We have to wait for Thunderbird 122, or you can try [beta](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/download/beta/).

If they get comments from users that the beta is performing correctly (send later mail is placed as unread into the Outbox, sent mail is placed as read into the Sent folder), they may release the fix soon.